# Input n space separated integer in c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, cin

Generally we take input in string in such cases but How will we ensure that 
 string will contain N integer only not more than that ? 
Input format 
 
Line 1 : Integer n .
Line 2 : Price for n days (separated by space). It can contain duplicate values .

Comment: Read N integers from the string, and then try to read one more. You should get an 'end of file' failure.

Comment: What's your point? My comment still applies. Try and read one more integer than you are expecting, the last read should fail. That's your test.

Comment: "_Generally we take input in string in..._"  - can you please edit it to make it your personal question? Also, you stated a C++ question: Your [mcve] does not compile.

Comment: we need n space separated integer  and we are taking input in string what if user try to enter more than n integer . How can we make sure that he will just enter  n integer not less not more  .

Comment: What exactly have you tried that didn't work as expected?

Comment: @Visluck Improve your question instead of answering comments.

Comment: @Visluck I keep telling you one possible answer. What is it about it that you don't like?

Comment: @john Thanx for your help .

Comment: @TedLyngmo  I am new to stack overflow and in future i will make sure that tag's are appropriate . Sorry for any  inconvenience .

Comment: @Visluck +1 With proper questions you'll soon get answers that are world class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int n;
  char a;
  printf("How many digit you want to take???");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  scanf("%c", &a);
  char name[2*n];
  printf("Enter Numbers");
  fgets(name,2*n,stdin);
  printf("You Entered :: %s",name);
  return(0);
 }
```

Even if you enter more than n numbers , it array won't store . You can always use strlen(name) [from String.h] to get length of char array for special conditioning